# Difference between Skimmer and Rocketeer?

Tags: diep.io

There was an update and a new tank was added to Diep.io on 12/22/2017. It's called Rocketeer and branches off Destroyer.

What are the differences between Rocketeer and Skimmer? They look very similar.

[image: Rocketeer (new tank)]

Rocketeer

[image: Skimmer]

Skimmer

Answer (score 2):

It's different as they have different paths of missiles following behind the big bullet. Also, Rocketeer is much smaller and easier to be damaged

Answer (score 2):

According to the wiki:

**Skimmer**

> A similar design to the Hunter but with wider Cannons, this tank has a Deployer and shoots a Destroyer Bullet with two Small Cannons attached at its back flanks. However, the main Bullet’s damage is significantly decreased. These bullets are known as missiles. As of press (Keyboard) time, only this tank and the Rocketeer use missiles.

**Rocketeer**

> The Rocketeer fires bullets with a Machine Gun Barrel on it's back, propelling the bullet forward. These too are missiles, as above.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the *Skimmer* and the *Rocketeer* is that they shoot different missiles, as said in **Damek**'s answer. Another difference between these two tanks is that a rocketeer's missile can have low bullet penetration and still survive after going through a tank. I've also heard that the rocketeer's missiles can shoot through the base camps in teams, unlike the skimmer and other tanks in diep.io.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Skimmer shoots mini Flank Guards.
Rocketeer shoots mini Machine Guns.